# mongodb $nin on ObjectId not working

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run an update subquery style with a not in clase on MongoDB but its not working. I believe its because the `toArray` casts the `ObjectIds` to text instead of leaving it as a `DBRef`. Below is my code:

```
var items = db.listsProducts.find({_id: {$exists: true}}, {product: true, _id: false}).toArray();
db.products.update({_id: {$nin: items}}, {$set: {'status':'inactive'}},{multi:true});
```

'product' is the DBRef field in the listProducts collection.
'products' is the collection I'm trying to update.

Instead of updating fields that are not in 'items', it updates all documents.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

listsProducts:

> {
>      "_id" : ObjectId("54e4bf7bade0276f008b4567"),
>      "__type" : "Core\Libs\Listing\Entity\Product",
>      "type" : "inventoryItem",
>      "product" : DBRef("products", ObjectId("54e308e23b8e778d128b4799")),
>      "list" : DBRef("lists", ObjectId("54e4aeab5252416c008b4569")),
>      "inventoryData" : {
>          "__type" : "Core\Libs\Listing\Entity\Product\InventoryData",
>          "parLevel" : NumberLong(0),
>          "itemsOnHand" : NumberLong(0)
>      },
>      "timeLog" : {
>          "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entity\TimeLog",
>          "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-18T16:36:11.387+0000"),
>          "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-07-07T07:31:25.900+0000"),
>          "deletedAt" : null
>      }
>   }

products:

> {
>      "_id" : ObjectId("54e308d83b8e778d128b4588"),
>      "__type" : "Core\Libs\Product\Entity\Product",
>      "name" : "Carrot Slices",
>      "gtin" : "10071179184300",
>      "status" : "active",
>      "defaultPrice" : NumberLong(0),
>      "references" : {
>          "__type" : "Core\Libs\Product\Entity\Product\References",
>          "manufacturer" : DBRef("manufacturers",  ObjectId("54e308d73b8e778d128b4569")),
>          "category" : DBRef("1ws-categories",  ObjectId("53e1e8723b8e77a52b8b45fd"))
>      },
>      "information" : {
>          "__type" : "Core\Libs\Product\Entity\Product\Information",
>          "description" : {
>              "__type" : "Core\Libs\Product\Entity\Product\Description",
>              "short" : "Carrot Smooth Sli 1/20#",
>              "long" : "Simplot Classic - Carrot Smooth Sli 1/20#"
>          },
>          "attributes" : {
>              "__type" : "Xeeo\Services\Core\Abstracts\Collection",
>              "entities" : [
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Brand Name",
>                      "value" : "Simplot Classic"
>                  },
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Manufacturer GLN",
>                      "value" : "0071179000009"
>                  },
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Manufacturer Name",
>                      "value" : "J. R. Simplot Company"
>                  },
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Country Of Origin",
>                      "value" : "US"
>                  },
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Last Modified Date",
>                      "value" : "2014-12-03T09:42:04"
>                  },
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Publication Date",
>                      "value" : "2011-10-26T00:00:00"
>                  },
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Start Availability Date",
>                      "value" : "2014-12-03T00:00:00"
>                  },
>                  {
>                      "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entities\KeyValuePair",
>                      "key" : "Depth (IN)",
>                      "value" : "13.375"
>                  }
>              ]
>          }
>      },
>      "images" : "http://www.fsenetportal.com/FSENetimages.nsf/0/BB29958620D9515A87257AA6005068B1/$file/10071179184300_A1CD.jpg?OpenElement",
>      "elasticSearchIndexStatus" : "indexed",
>      "timeLog" : {
>          "__type" : "Core\Utils\Entity\TimeLog",
>          "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-17T09:24:40.138+0000"),
>          "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-03-25T00:56:21.219+0000"),
>          "deletedAt" : null
>      }
>   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{_id: {$nin: items}}` expects an array of `ObjectIds` and from what I can see you're passing an array of documents and what's even worse you seem to be telling mongo not to select `_id` in your `find`query.

This is how I would go about this.

```
var items = db.listsProducts.find({_id: {$exists: true}}, {product: true, _id: true}).toArray();

var itemIds = items.map(function(i) {
    return i._id;
});

db.products.update({_id: {$nin: itemIds}}, {$set: {status: 'inactive'}}, {multi: true});
```

Comment: "product" is a DBRef so what I need the map function to return is i.product._id. But when I update your map function to return i.product._id I get the following: WriteResult({
 "nMatched" : 0,
 "nUpserted" : 0,
 "nModified" : 0,
 "writeError" : {
  "code" : 2,
  "errmsg" : "ArrayFilterEntries equality cannot be undefined"
 }
})

Comment: Can you post an example of a document from both the `items` and `products`collections?

Comment: i figured it out. it should be this: return i.product.$id;

Comment: ```{_id: {$exists: true}}``` is redundant since it always exists for every object in every collection